# ¿Por qué "corbeta", siendo una palabra proveniente del francés "corvette", se adaptó con "b"?

Tags: vocabulario, etimología, ortografía

Acabo de toparme con esta palabra en el diccionario:

> **[corbeta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ap1NIeq)**
>
> Del fr. *corvette*.
>
> 1. f. Buque de guerra de características similares a la fragata, pero con menor tonelaje y autonomía.
> 2. f. Antiguo buque de guerra, con tres palos y vela cuadrada, semejante a la fragata, aunque más pequeña.

Me ha llamado la atención que la adaptación al español de la palabra fuese con "b", supongo que por el hecho de haber visto más veces la palabra usada en el Chevrolet Corvette que en la propia palabra *corbeta*.

Otras palabras que vienen del francés no han sufrido ese cambio:

- Revancha (del francés *revanche*).
- Avalancha (del francés *avalanche*).
- Vitral (del francés *vitrail*).

Y las que en francés eran con "b" han seguido manteniendo la "b":

- Debatirse (del francés *se débattre*).
- Briñón (del francés *brugnon*).

¿Es este caso un caso puntual, o existen otras palabras que hayan sufrido el mismo cambio? Y en cualquier caso, ¿a qué obecede este cambio de letra? ¿Tal vez por similitud con la palabra *orbe*, ya de uso en el siglo XIII? ¿O porque [*corveta*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B3d2fdL) ya se usaba con otro significado más orientado a la hípica?

Comment: EL NTLLE no da información sobre qué etimología se asocia a una palabra y a partir de cuándo. Lo digo porque hasta bien entrado el siglo XIX se sugiere la etimología de _liburnica celer_. Además, en el 1899 y hasta 1947 se indica que viene del latín_corbita_ (de _corbis_, canasto). No es hasta 1956 cuando se recoge el origen francés.

Comment: @fedorqui pues mira, puede ser eso mezclado con que acabo de ver que _corveta_ ya estaba pillado en español con otro significado hípico completamente diferente.

Comment: Jaja, será eso. De hecho, ¿se tendrá en cuenta esta variable en algún caso? Si ya existe variante exacta -> busca la más parecida.

Answer (score 1):

Todo parece indicar que la etimología original es desconocida, si bien me extrañaría que un país con tanta tradición marítima como España tomara del francés una palabra de este tipo.

Tal y como hemos visto en los comentarios, un paseo por el Nuevo tesoro lexicográfico de la lengua española ([NTLLE](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle)) nos muestra la evolución de la palabra en los diccionarios del español.

En **1721** Bluteau dice:

> Corbeta. *Curvêta*

En **1786** Terreros y Pando:

> Corbeta, corbetear, V. Corveta, &c.

Mirando en *corveta* vemos:

> Corvete, especie de fragata, V.

Y a continuación tiene otra entrada con *corveta* en la que detalla extensamente la acepción relacionada con los caballos.

Sin embargo, esta es la única entrada en la que aparece *corveta* con *v* para referirse a la embarcación.

Eso sí, existe la curiosidad de que en **1705** Sobrino habla de:

> Corbetas, f. courbettes, que fait le cheval.

Es decir que asocia la versión con *b* a la de los caballos.

---

A partir de allí, vemos ya en **1803**:

> Embarcación ligera de tres palos y vela quadra. *Liburnica celer*.

La asociación con la etimología de *liburnica celer* aguanta hasta 1852. Hay después unas cuantas obras que no mencionan etimología alguna, hasta que en **1884** la Academia Usual dice:

> Corbeta. (Del lat. *corbita*, nave pesada; de *corbis*, cesta.) f. Embarcación ligera de tres palos y vela cuadrada, semejante á la fragata, aunque más pequeña. Á veces tiene el palo mesana sin cofas ni vergas.

Así aguanta muchos años, última referencia en 1947. En 1950 no menciona etimología alguna y en **1956** finalmente encontramos:

> Corbeta. (Del fr. *corvette*) f. Embarcación ligera de tres palos y vela cuadrada, semejante á la fragata, aunque más pequeña

Comment: Es curioso. La etimología de _corbita_ y esta de _corbis_, que efectivamente significa "cesta" en latín antiguo, parecía razonable. Sin embargo, según la teoría actual proviene del francés _corvette_ y, según el Larousse, esta viene del [neerlandés medio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_Dutch) _corver_, pero no encuentro qué significa eso ni de dónde viene. No sé si al final ambas etimologías podrían llegar al mismo sitio, pero sería interesante.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo que viniera del neerlandés sí tendría más sentido, por su historial marítimo. Además, _corver_ suena bastante de allí. Busco pero no encuentro más referencias...